# form_for - generate unique ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I am trying to figure out how to assign a unique id to each form that appears on my page, for example lets say i have 5 form_for on my page, each form is going to have the same id (this is a form to create a new object)

```
<%= form_for @document || Document.new, :html => { multipart: true, class: 'upload_document' } do |f| %>
```

If i was editing multiple objects then I could grab the id of @document but i don't have anything to grab

I know i can also use namespace, but again this would just generate the same ids with the same namespace..unless i can increment the value of the namespace?

What would be the best way to approach this please

Thanks

Comment: What about the `object_id` of the newly created object?

Comment: do you mean when @document has been initialized? it then gets assigned an id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object#object_id`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/object_id):

> ... Returns an integer identifier for obj. The same number will be
>   returned on all calls to id for a given object, and **no two active
>   objects will share an id**.

```
<% object = @document || Document.new %>
<%= form_for object, :html => { multipart: true, id: object.object_id.to_s } do |f| %>
```

This can be hard to declare own `object` for each `form_for`, i recommend create array with 5 objects and iterate through it.

Comment: thank you very much, something else that i have learned today